# using Jquery to find out what check boxes are checked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that i am enumerating through my model with.
I have this check box there for each row.

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="IsSelected" value="<%=item.PartNo%>" />
```

I would like to use jquery to find out which of the check boxes are checked
I tried doing this

```
  var selected = $("#IsSelected").val();
```

but selected is just undefined.
is there a way to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var checkedCheckboxes = $("input[name='IsSelected']:checked");
```

`checkedCheckboxes` should then be a collection of the checked checkboxes

Comment: ok let say I want to display in an alert which boxes are selected?
using alert(selected) just shows "object"

and alert(selected[0]) shows [objecteInputElement]

how would I work with them to get the values of them?

Comment: @twal Try $.each(checkedCheckboxes,function(k,v){ alert(v.val();)});

Comment: $.each(checkedCheckboxes,function(k,v){ alert(v.val();)}); 
gives me an error saying unexpected ;
if I remove the ; after val(); 
I get an error saying Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: sorry. how about: $("input[name='IsSelected']:checked").each(function(i,e){alert($(this).val())})

Comment: Great thank you very much. I made a small change to make all of the selected values appear in one alert like this:

       var checkedCheckboxes = $("input[name='IsSelected']:checked");
        var checkedString = "";
        $("input[name='IsSelected']:checked").each(function (i, e) { checkedString += ($(this).val()) })
        alert(checkedString);

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should change your code to

```
<input type="checkbox" id="IsSelected" name="IsSelected" value="<%=item.PartNo%>" />
```

You can use jquery [.is(':checked')](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to determine if checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Because the OP is enumerating a collection of items and thus outputting the same element potentially multiple times on the same page, the `id` attribute should NOT be used as you suggest. The `id` attribute must be unique in the document.

Comment: Yeah, right! I just wanted to point out that $('#IsSelected') will not work if IsSelected is name.